# Json Table Sorting?

Tags: json

I have a table that populates prices from two apis. Unfortuantly this isn't sorted. Annoyingly. On each api however, it is sorted ^_^ So the issue i have is say site b is cheaper than site a. As it currenlty stands wouldn't work.

Heres my code. at the moment its just one api.

Forgot to mention, As it stands its site a ontop of site b in the same table. if there is a row thats cheaper tthen the row would have to move preferably.

Sam

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'api link here',
    success: function (json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {
            var title = json.results[i].section;
            var price = json.results[i].price;
            var href = json.results[i].quantity;
            var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='button link'>Link</button>";
           $("#apple").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+href+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
           $("#apple").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
               location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
           });
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to sort the data coming back from your ajax request before rendering it? If so, that's very simple to do (and I'll post an answer) or something else). P.S. I suggest clearing up the wording. As it stands even if somebody solves your issue, the question won't be helpful for those that come later.

Comment: Sorry, My actual question is how would i go about sorting the price from two api's to lowest first in the same table.

Comment: Believe thats what i am wanting to do. I have multiple apis in the same table but im wanting the multiple apis to be sorted so that the lowest price is shown. Rather than the lowest price of the first api i put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So (assuming I understand this correctly), you want to have the rendered data be sorted by price? Luckily, that's easy to do :).

Here's a js fiddle so you can experiement: http://jsfiddle.net/e9sdb91v/

Here's the basic code you need:

```
success: function (data) {
    var json = data.sort(sorter);
    // Rest of your code goes here
}
```

You need to obviously write the sorter function as well:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    return (a.price - b.price);
}
```

That's basically it, sorter can be as simple or complex as you like (this will sort your objects from low to high on price). Just sort, then render.

If you need further clarification, just post a comment :).

Note: This sorts the data before rendering, so it assumes you are starting from scratch each time, if you are trying to add rows dynamically into the correct place in the `#apple` div, then that'll be slightly different (and you'll need to amend your question).

Comment: Sorry only time i've had a chance to get around t this. Could you look at my other post and help. Thanks